# Different behaviour in Eclipse than in NetBeans

Tags: java

The DeviceList returns a Vector of size 0 in Eclipse works fine in netbeans i want to work in eclipse

```
Vector deviceList = CaptureDeviceManager.getDeviceList(new RGBFormat());
```

Comment: Question as headline is quite - dunno - you should put some effort in asking questions here ;)

Answer (score 6):

The semantics of a Java program has nothing to do with what IDE you execute it from.

If the code works differently in Eclipse than what it does in NetBeans you should check that you

- use the same libraries (compile time / runtime)
- use the same program arguments to start the program.
- start the VM with the same command line options